# FORTRAN WRITE()

Tags: io, fortran, fortran77

Before I begin, I must preface by stating that I am a novice when it comes to FORTRAN. I am maintaining a legacy piece of code from 1978. It's purpose is to read in some data values from a file, process the values, and then output the processed values to another text file.

Given the following FORTRAN code:

```
      INTEGER NM,STUBS,I,J,K
      PARAMETER (NM=67,STUBS=43)
      INTEGER*4 MDS(STUBS,NM)

      CALL OPEN$A(A$RDWR,'/home/test/data.txt', MAXPATHLEN,1)
      CALL OPEN$A(A$WRIT,'out',11,2)

      DO 90 I=1,2
          READ(1,82) STUB     
          !-- data processing --!     
          WRITE(2,80) STUB,(MDS(I,J),J=1,24)
90    CONTINUE

80    FORMAT(/1X,A24,25I5)
82    FORMAT(1X,A24,25F5,1)
```

My question is in regards to the `WRITE()` statement.

I understand that `(2,80)` refers to the file output stream opened and pointing to the file `'out'` and referenced by the numeral 2. I understand that 80 refers to the format statement referenced by label 80.

`STUB` is used to store the values read from file input 1. These values are what is processed, and saved into `MDS(I,J)` in the `!-- data processing --!` section that I have omitted.

Am I correct in assuming that `(MDS(I,J),J=1,24)` will write 24 integer values to the output file? In other words, looping from 1 to 24?

Comment: @Fortranner When adding the tags you should clean up the formating or other problems in the question as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.  The syntax `(MDS(I,J), J=1,24)` is an "[implied DO-loop](http://www.pcc.qub.ac.uk/tec/courses/f90/stu-notes/F90_notesMIF_9.html#HEADING120)" and is commonly used in situations like this.

Comment: You're welcome.  I added a link to a some documentation on this if you're interested.

Comment: Thank you! I've perused that site and it's definitely been a help with this modification! Much appreciated.