# Need examples of complex fortran format statements?

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to write a data parser in C# to use when translating fortran programs to .NET. The thing works by taking a file, the fortran format string and an array of variables to populate with the results of the file.

I am looking for some examples of real and complex fortran format statements. Preferably with lots of nesting, repeats, literal fields etc. Something which will break my code basically.

Please don't suggest that I make them up myself, I have already done that and surprise things work like a charm at the moment. I haven't got enough experience with Fortran to have seen what format statements look like when they get really complex.

If somebody has some examples they wouldn't mind sharing, even just a single example, I'd be most grateful.

Comment: There's a lot of Fortran code available on the www. Can you be specific about the ways in which that corpus is inadequate to support your testing ?  What additional help could this old hacker possibly provide ?

Comment: I have tried to google it, but I have only come across really simple format statements, simpler than the ones I put together for testing. If you know of a piece of code that contains a complex format statement I'd be most grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd point you to a couple of resources that may help a bit:
[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126324/fortran-write). Another one which is [more general] and has several code examples [2](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap05/format.html). You should clarify which version of Fortran that you are aiming for. Hope this helps you get going.